# How to pre-populate a field with the current users name?

Tags: 6, entities

I want to pre-populate a form field with the value from another cck field from a different content type. I have been looking into using the prepopulate module and pathauto to get the correct url, but I am not sure that these will work. I am new to drupal and kinda lost in the storm with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question posed in the title of this question, you could in a custom module do something along the lines of...

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if ($form_id=='NODETYPE_node_form') {
     $form['field_FIELD'][0]['#default_value']['value']=$user->name;
  }

  // any other form alters you need

}
```

where MYMODULE is the name of your custom module, NODETYPE is the content type in question and FIELD is the field name in question without the field_ prefix.  Now, whenever you are editing or creating a content type of NODETYPE, the FIELD in question will have a prefilled default value of the current user's name.

Now, if this is a different form, you'll just need to adjust the $form_id== construct to point to that form, the field in that form, etc, but the rest of the logic should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it would apply to your situation, and I'm sorry I don't really have time to check it out completely at the moment, but you could try using [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate). By using Entity Reference, the new content type will be related back to the user in a way that can be utilized by views and many other modules. I just realized, though, that it looks like you tagged this as Drupal 6, so this solution may not work for you if you cannot move to Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks but yes I am using d6. I am sure it would be easier in d7 but currently thats not an option.