# Populate fields when a checkbox is clicked on a form

Tags: 7, forms

I have a regular drupal 7 form (based on a content type called guests) where I need a "Bring my partner" checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked, a field collection field (first name/last name/address) needs to be prefilled basing on the details for the currently logged-in user. (Partner details are in my user account details.)

Can this be done in `hook_form_alter()`? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: prefill as in it will automatically add these using javascript or do you want to add these values to the form data after it is submitted?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37867/how-to-pre-populate-a-field-with-the-current-users-name

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) and add a state to the field that needs to be hidden.

```
$form["first_name"] = array(
    "#states" => array(
        "invisible" => array(
            ":input[name='bring_parter']" => array(
                "checked" => FALSE,
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

What this does is hides the "first_name" unless "bring_partner" is checked. [More info here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#states)